# With Regex, I want to match the first set of numbers before 'x' within each group of numbers delimited by a comma

Tags: regex

I have a list of dimensional values (HxLxW) that are delimited by a comma. I want to match all the H values from this list of dimensions.

```
11" x 8" x 21" (S), 12" x 9" x 21" (M), 13" x 10" x 21" (L)
```

I would like to end up with something like

```
11" (S), 12" (M), 13" (L)
```

I am still new at REGEX and still trying to wrap my head around all the concepts. I tried a few things but without any matches.

```
(\d+.).(?<=x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Quite quick and dirty, but this should give you two groups per Comma separated "size":

```
(?<height>\d+)"\sx\s\d+"\sx\s\d+" (?<size>\(\w\))
```

(?\d+) is your first capture group (named height), it expects any number of digits followed by " x "

(?(\w)) is your second, it expects to find any "word" in brackets. This will get you your label.

Answer (score 0):

Use a positive lookahead that matches the `x L x W` part.

```
(?:\d+(?="\s*x\s*\d+"\s*x\s*\d+"))|\([SML]\),?
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/aFSHDQ/1)

You can replace `[SML]` with another pattern if there are other sizes.

Answer (score 0):

The capture groups match what you need:

```
(\d+").*?(\([A-Z]\),?) *?(?:,|$)
```

##### [Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/FuMqmd/1)

##### The regular expression matches as follows:

| Node | Explanation |
| --- | --- |
| `(` | group and capture to \1: |
| `\d+` | digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `"` | " |
| `)` | end of \1 |
| `.*?` | any character except \n (0 or more times (matching the least amount possible)) |
| `(` | group and capture to \2: |
| `\(` | ( |
| `[A-Z]` | any character of: 'A' to 'Z' |
| `\)` | ) |
| `,?` | ',' (optional (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `)` | end of \2 |
| `*?` | space (0 or more times (matching the least amount possible)) |
| `(?:` | group, but do not capture: |
| `,` | , |
| `|` | OR |
| `$` | before an optional \n, and the end of the string anchor |
| `)` | end of grouping |

Answer (score 0):

You can simply replace matches of the following regular expression with an empty string.

```
x[^\(]+
```

This reads, "match 'x' followed by one or more (`+`) characters other than (`^` at the beginning of the character class) `'('`".

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fMIF2a/1)

Answer (score 0):

The pattern `(\d+.).(?<=x)` that you tried captures 1+ digits and a single char other than a newline in group 1, and then matches any character followed by asserting that the character to the left is `x`

Which is the same as `(\d+.)x`, but in your example data the part `(\d+.)x` will match `11"x` but not `11" x` due to the missing space.

---

If the dimensions are comma delimited, you can use 2 capture groups with a negated character class that excludes matching a comma:

```
\b(\d+")[^,]*(\([SML]\),?)
```

**Explanation**

- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial word match
- `(\d+")` Capture **group 1**, match 1+ digits and `"`
- `[^,]*` Match optional characters other than a comma
- `(\([SML]\),?)` Capture **group 2**, match `(` then one of `S` `M` `L` and `)` followed by an optional comma

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hbV6sn/1)

If you want to match the optional leading whitespace characters and not a trailing comma:

```
(\s*\b\d+")[^,]*(\([SML]\)(?:,(?!\s*$))?)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/k7k8qY/1)

If there should be an `x` char present:

```
(\d+")\s*x\b[^(),]*(\([SML]\),?)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PlGzFx/1)